# Where do I find .war files in Aerogear unified push server?

Tags: aerogear

Where can find unifiedpush-server-wildfly.war and unifiedpush-auth-server.war files in unified push server. where can i deploy it?

Comment: If the below answer is acceptable, please choose it as the answer to benefit  others.

Answer (score 0):

It's located at {your_jboss_installation_root_folder}/standalone/deployments/, you can just drop your .war files there and JBoss will automatically deploy them.

If the .war is successfully deployed, you will see a file such as unifiedpush-auth-server.war.deployed being generated in the same folder.

Otherwise, files such as unifiedpush-auth-server.war.failed will be generated. It is a text file so open it you will find why it failed to deploy in JBoss.

Hope this helps.